# Google Calendar API Usage Limits

Tags: google-calendar-api

Currently I am working with Google Calendar integration in our product. I am very new to the Google Calendar API. 
As a first step, I have gone through the Google API documentation, and I am little bit confused with the Calendar API usage limits. I have the following questions regarding this:

1. What is the usage limit for Calendar API? I have seen as 500,000 requests per day. Is this limit based on the hosting domain/URL or a particular user?
2. In some other document, it says 10,000. Is this limit for one user? Can I get the details of how it is counting?
3. Can I use the Javascript API for integration since Google released it for beta version?
   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js
4. Which will be useful: either the Javascript API or the server side API? Is there any difference in usage limit between the Javascript API and server side API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, 2: Currently it is 500 000 queries a day per project. That means all your users combined can make at maximum 500k queries a day. There is also a per-user limit of 5 queries per second which you can change in the console (console.developers.google.com). If you need more queries per day, you can submit a quota request through the console.

3, 4: yes, you can certainly use javascript. There is no difference in limits for server vs. client apps.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 and 2 the current quotas (set maximum by default) are as follows:
Queries per day: 1,000,000
Queries per 100 seconds per user: 500